# Xcode - add library to only one target

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode8

I have a Swift project with a library that is not available for simulator. Therefore I created two targets, one to run on device, one in the simulator. I want to add the library only to the device target.

What I did:

- added preprocessor macros: SIMULATOR=1 for simulator target, SIMULATOR=0 for device target
- I 'Link binary with Libraries' only for device target, 'Compile sources' also only on device target
- in code I use #if !SIMULATOR guards for the code related to library

Still, when trying to build for simulator I get a linker error:

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_VuforiaManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MainViewController.o

What else do I need to do?